# Creating News Letter in Asp.NET

Tags: asp.net, newsletter

Do you guys know how to write newsletter subscription in asp.net ? Is there any practice for that or we simply should use a standard way to build newsletter subscription like a table and saving e-mails into this table. When admin clicks send button of an e-mail and all the recipients get the e-mail.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no fast hard rules. It all depends on what features your business requires.

I'm not sure about abroad, but in the US it's required by [law (Can SPAM 2003)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAN-SPAM_Act_of_2003) to give the user an unsubscribe feature.

By saving the emails in a database, you can easily automate the unsubscribe feature.

Comment: Actually it's all about people subscribed and get e-mails from the site admin. No need an advanced GUI to create e-mail. Simply a FCK editor actually is enough for all e-mail creation process.

Comment: Upss, That's important. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There's an [ASP.Net Newsletter project](http://www.codeplex.com/newsletter) on Codeplex.  You might want to have a look at what they do for inspiration, or perhaps just use that project.